# Global access of config from database in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using expressjs and want to store project config variables in database for some reason. What is best way to access config variables from database so I will not need to query database on each router i am loading.

Should I use app.locals?

Comment: Do you considered create a file named  `confi.json` with the configuration information and to import in the `app.js`? This file could be the database of the config.

Comment: my configs are stored in database. Will json able to query database?

Comment: How do you query database (mongoose, sequelize, etc) and whats configuration can be reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I don't export the "router" directly but a function that accept an argument which will receive the config. Here's an example :

```
// router.js
module.exports = function(database) {
  return {
    getLogin: function(req, res) {
      // database exist here
    }
  }
}

// app.js without the creation of app and database
var app = express();
var database = require('./database');

var router = require('./router')(database)
app.get('/login', getLogin);
```

This way, you have the modularity and the possibility to interact easily with the database.

Comment: Thanks @swatto but in this way if I have 20 routers, I will need to add this function in each file?